# How do you know when a for loop in python will iterate over a letter or an index?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I'm working on some code here:

```
# Codecademy "9. Scrabble"
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

x = "DuVeT"
total = 0
for i in x:
    print score[i.lower()]
    total += score[i.lower()]    
print total
```

My question is:
How do I know when the "i" in a for loop will actually be an index number vs. the actual character? In this case, when I go through the loop the first time, i = "D". I thought i would = 0 for the index. Can you help me understand how you would know when a for loop operates with index numbers vs letters?

Comment: In python, `for in` loops always iterate over values, not indices.

Comment: It will never be a counter unless you explicitly make it one (using for example `range` or `enumerate`). The normal behaviour is to go through the "iterable" (the thing after `in`) and assign the individual values to the loop variable one after the other. If you need a counter you can use `for i, item in enumerate(x):`

Comment: @Hamms That's not correct. A `for` loop will iterate over what the iterator returns. In case of a dictionary it is the key not the value.

Comment: @KlausD. - The value of the key, not the key's corresponding value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The key is the index of a dictionary. An index does not need to be an integer.

Comment: This website is not a replacement for a basic [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: @KlausD. - That's right. A loop iterates over a view of those keys. The keys are data just like their attached values. A list's indices aren't stored, but a dictionary's keys are (like a set's elements).

Answer (score 0):

You look at the thing after "for i in": this is an *iterable* object.  In the case you present, **x** is a string; its elements are characters.

If you want to iterate over the index locations, you have to get the length of the object and iterate over that, such as:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    print score[x[i].lower()]
```

Do you see how that works?  When you work with the index, you use it as a subscript in the string to get the one character you need.

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

1. For mapping types (`dict`, related classes from `collections`), iteration is over the keys of the mapping
2. For most anything that's not a mapping, e.g. `tuple`, `list`, `str`, `bytes`, `set`, etc., iteration is over the values.

If you need the index for a sequence as well as the value, you almost always want the `enumerate` function, e.g.

```
for i, x in enumerate(someseq):
```

Similarly, to get the key and value from a mapping, you want the `items` method (`iteritems` on Py2):

```
for k, v in mymapping.items():
```